# How can I make a button to open a modal window in which a message will go?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make a button which opens a modal window in which a message will go

I tried to add a label when I view the page the window that I want to be displayed is on top of the rest of the page content but when I press the button it does nothing

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>CarpiShop</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.9.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/toastify-js/src/toastify.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/index.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="wrapper">
        <header class="header-mobile">
            <h1 class="logo"> </h1>
            <button class="open-menu" id="open-menu">
                <i class="bi bi-list"></i>
            </button>
        </header>
        <aside>
            <button class="close-menu" id="close-menu">
                <i class="bi bi-x"></i>
            </button>
            <header>
                <div class="user">
                    <i class="bi bi-person-circle"></i>
                </div>
                <h1 class="logo"> <input class="busqueda-productos" type="text" placeholder="¿ que estas buscando? "></h1>
            </header>
            <nav>
                <ul class="menu">
                    <li class="">
                       
                        <div class="btn">
                            <i class="bi bi-search"></i>
                        </div>
                        
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <button id="todos los productos" class="boton-menu boton-categoria active"><i class="bi bi-hand-index-thumb-fill"></i> Todos los productos</button>
                    </li>
                    <div>
                        <div id="filtros" class="boton-menu boton-categoria"></i></div>
                        <label for="filtros">
                            <i class="bi bi-hand-index-thumb"></i>  filtros
                        </label>
                        <div>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="nose">
                         <div class="container-filtros">
                            <div class="contenido-filtros">
                                <h4>desde</h4><input type="number" step="0.01"><h4>hasta</h4><input type="number" step="0.01" min="0" max="1.000.000.000.000">
                                <div class="ubicacion">
                                    <i class="bi bi-geo-alt-fill">ubicacion</i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cerrar">
                                        <label for="filtros"></label>
                                        <i class="bi bi-backspace-fill"></i>
                        </div>

                            </div>
                         </div>
                        <button id="vender" class="boton-menu boton-categoria"><i class="bi bi-hand-index-thumb"></i>¿quiere vender algo?</button>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <button id="p.q.r.s" class="boton-menu boton-categoria"><i class="bi bi-hand-index-thumb"></i> P.Q.R.S</button>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="boton-menu boton-carrito" href="./carrito.html">
                            <i class="bi bi-cart-fill"></i> Carrito <span id="numerito" class="numerito">0</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <footer>
                <p class="texto-footer">© hecho por biombrock</p>
            </footer>
        </aside>
        <main>
            <h2 class="titulo-principal" id="titulo-principal">Todos los productos</h2>
            <div id="contenedor-productos" class="contenedor-productos">
             
            </div>
        </main>
    </div>
    
    
</body>
</html>
```

modify the question and add the label to help me (I appreciate your attention and help

Comment: Where is your modal that should be opened?

Comment: I did this I don't know if it works for me or not

Comment: What you have are two forms, but I don't see the modal in your code.

Answer (score 1):

First, I did not see any modal in ur existing code and you need JavaScript along with your existing HTML and CSS code to achieve that, I just create simple modal, like this:

```js
// Function to open the modal
function openModal() {
    const modal = document.getElementById("modal");
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// Function to close the modal
function closeModal() {
    const modal = document.getElementById("modal");
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// Add a click event listener to the "REGISTRATE" button
const openModalButton = document.getElementById("openModal");
openModalButton.addEventListener("click", openModal);
```

```css
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hide the modal by default */
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

/* Modal content */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: 15% auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 400px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

/* Close button */
.close {
    float: right;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- ... Rest of your HTML code ... -->
        
        <div id="modal" class="modal">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <span class="close" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
                <p id="message">Your message goes here.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button id="openModal" class="register">REGISTRATE</button>
        
        <!-- ... Rest of your HTML code ... -->
    </body>
</html>
```

You can modify the code to meet your specific requirements. Hope it will help you :)

Comment: I am going to modify the label that you sent me and I am going to apply it to my page, thank you very much for your help friend

Comment: Okay glad to help you friend. Keep the spirit of learning web development, try and experiment a lot, and don't forget to check the console in the browser's developer tools if you encounter errors :)

Comment: the first code is js, the second code is css an the last is html ?

Comment: Yup, that is correct

Comment: and how can i add these modal windows to my html code? I have tried in different ways but it does not work as it should

Comment: When do you want to show the modal? After register or what? And what message you want to show on the modal? I will help modify ur code